# dual screen programming issue

Tags: c#, .net, multiple-monitors

I am using VSTS 2008 + C#. Is there any way to get the informaiton like, whether we are currently in dual monitor mode, how much is the current resolution of each desktop?

BTW: there are two modes of dual screen, duplicate screen or extended screen. I need a solution as well to distinguish between the different modes.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Because, you know, there are video drivers that will make out a single screen out of two physical screens, so whatever you are attempting with regard to multiple screens might fail in that case. Anyway, I ask this question out of curiosity. And don't forget that two is not the limit :)

Comment: Actually I am using Windows Media Encoder to record screen, but when in dual screen desktop and resolution too high, my program will fail to start, here is what I described before.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876879/error-to-start-windows-media-encoder

BTW: I did not find any information about the maximum limitation of resolution of Windows Media Encoder in dual screen mode, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

[System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx)

> Gets an array of all displays on the
>   system.

The property [Primary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primary.aspx)

> Gets a value indicating whether a particular display is the primary device.

And the [Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx) property may be the solution for the rest.

[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VirtualScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen.aspx)  Property

Might be usefull for you, to determine if the primary monitor is cloned or extended.

VirtualScreen resolution higher than the ones of primary -> extended...

VirtualScreen resolution = the ones of primary -> cloned...

Comment: So, if more than one Screen element is in AllScreens? Means currently in multple user mode?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I did some experiment today. I am confused about what is the meaning of Top (and Left) property of Bounds property of Screen? For primary screen, I find they are always zero, but for non-primary screen, what is the meaning/function of Left/Top?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen
```

provides you with screen data. Duplicate screen is not really considered another screen from an application point of view.